# iOS Global menu with photo and gallery buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, appdelegate

I added my bottom menu in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)addBottomMenu
{
    BottomMenu *bottomMenu = [[BottomMenu alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [ScreenHelper getHeightOfScreen] - 70, 320, 70)];
    bottomMenu.delegate = self;
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] window] addSubview:bottomMenu];
}
```

I have 2 buttons in menu for take photo from gallery and for camera take photo. I want to this buttons work global same (in every controller). It should work that it would show gallery (or camera) and after user choose (or take) photo it navigates to same controller and show image. In controller I would add these lines of code:

```
- (void)photoButtonTapped
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark Image Picker delegates
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imageOfReceipt = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailReceiptSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

... where photoButtonTapped is from delegate. It's working (when I was trying bottom menu in controller, not now when I added to AppDelegate). In AppDelegate there is problem with presenting view controllers (I know why but I don't know how to bypass this). I need to get it working in AppDelegate. I don't want to duplicate this to every controller and change delegate in BottomMenu in AppDelegate. Is it possible to do it global?

Comment: Create a baseViewController and add all the image piking work in it and import the baseViewController in all the class. May it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Why not to call:

```
[self.navigationController.topViewController presentViewController:picker 
                                                          animated:YES 
                                                        completion:NULL];
```

If there is no navigationController property in AppDelegate, try to get currently presented View Controller in other way. For example try self.window.rootViewController. And you probably should discard from using segues.

Comment: I was thinking about both solution (this one and by Ashish Kakkad in comment) and I choose yours. Both solutions have pros and cons and in my project this one has more pros for me. Thanks